# How would I capitalize the first letter of a word in Java?

Tags: java, string, java-7

How would I capitalize the next word that comes after a period (.)?
For example.

> The sun rose. plants started to grow.

What would I need to do to capitalize the **p** in **plants**?

Comment: What kind of input component are you using?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 7):

Based on the way that you have asked this question, I am assuming that you are a beginner at programming in general, and Java programming in particular.

So the first answer is that there is no magic solution in Java; i.e. no "find and capitalize the first word of every sentence".  You (or someone) needs to solve it by *designing and writing some code*.

The way to solve the problem is to break it down into parts.  For example, here is ONE possible breakdown ...

1. Given an input String, split it into sentence Strings.
2. Given a sentence String, extract the first word.
3. Given a word, capitalize it.
4. Replace the first word of a sentence with a new word.
5. Turn a sequence of sentences back into a String.

Then code the above, and test them individually and together.  There are existing Java library APIs that can help you.  For instance:

- The [`String.split(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method splits a String based on a separator (e.g. a full stop, or a one or more white-space characters).
- The [`String.indexOf(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) methods finds the first position of a specific substring in a string.
- The [`String.substring(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) methods extracts a substring based on character offsets within the string.
- The [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class could be useful.
- And so on.

(Read the javadocs for each of these methods ...)

Once the code is working, you can refine it to make the code nicer (readable, maintainable, etc) and/or to make it run faster.

If you have problems with the above approach, feel free to ask follow-up questions.  But you need to show us your code ... or pseudo-code.

Comment: SringBuilder could be useful here also.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than attempting to find word and sentence boundaries yourself, you should use the [BreakIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html) class, a [sentence instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html#getSentenceInstance%28%29).

BreakIterator handles all the difficulty in detecting sentence boundaries for the specified locale too, such as a decimal point in a number not being a sentence boundary.

Here is some sample code that will transform a sentence:

```
String sentence = "The sun rose.  plants started to grow.";
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(sentence);

BreakIterator bi = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
bi.setText(sentence);
int pos;
do
{
    pos = bi.next();
    if (pos != BreakIterator.DONE && pos < buf.length())
        buf.setCharAt(pos, Character.toUpperCase(buf.charAt(pos)));
}
while (pos != BreakIterator.DONE);

String correctedSentence = buf.toString();
System.out.println(correctedSentence);
```

Comment: @akuhn BreakIterator has been around for a while (Java 1.1, possibly earlier).  Javadoc can use it to parse sentences if you pass it the `-breakiterator` option and it parses the first sentence of documentation better with it on (the text 'e.g.' in the first sentence will be parsed properly with it on but not off)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using regular expressions:

```
public String capitalizeSentences(String s) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\.\\s+\\w");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) m.appendReplacement(buf, m.group().toUpperCase());
    m.appendTail(buf);
    return buf.toString();
}
```

the pattern `/\.\s+\w/` matches a sequence of a dot, one or more spaces, and a word character.  Regular expressions are very powerful for string processing and supported by almost all programming languages. Learn their syntax once, and you'll be more productive in all languages!

**Edit:** *see @prunge's solution for a much more elegant solution using Java's `BreakIterator` class which breaks text into sentences.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String phrase = "The sun rose. plants started to grow";

// Split every sentence
String[] sentences = phrase.split(".");

String capitalized = "";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// Process every sentence
for (String str : sentences){
    // Trim the sentence. It might have a space in the beginning
    String result = str.trim();
    // get the first char
    String fc = "" + result.charAt(0);
    // Replace with capitalized one
    result = result.replace(fc, fc.toUpperCase());
    sb.append(result);
    sb.append(". "); // A full-stop and space
}

capitalized = sb.toString();
```

Comment: It's sad that you didn't try in the least. -1

Comment: You should avoid using `+` on string. It is slow. You'd better use `str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1)`, and also you'd better use a `StringBuilder` to compose the final result.

Comment: You still have string concatenation in your code. You should avoid all of these. Behind the scenes, for each `+` the Java compiler creates a new StringBuilder instance, calls append once and throws the instance away, so better call append in your sb in the first place!

Answer (score -1):

could you parse the entire sentence, and your delimiter would be a full stop. then from the example above you would essentially have 2 strings; "The sun rose", and " plants started to grow", you could then get the second character of each one, (taking the space after the full stop to be the first character) and capitalize that.

```
public class mainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String phrase = " The sun rose. plants started to grow.";
    String delims = "\\."; //full stop as delimiter
    String[] tokens = phrase.split(delims);

    String capitalizedLetter;
    String word;
    String capitalizedWord;

    for(String sentence: tokens)
    {
    capitalizedLetter = sentence.substring(0, 2).toUpperCase();
    word = sentence.substring(2);
    capitalizedWord = capitalizedLetter + word;
    System.out.println(capitalizedWord + "."); //to include the missing full-stop
    } 

}
```

}

Hope this helps! best of luck!

Comment: wrong, sentence.charAt(1) would return a char not a string, n whats toUpper ?? its toUppercase in string

Comment: 1) `String phrase = "The sun rose. plants started to grow."` should have a `;` at the end. 2) `capitalizedSentence = sentence.charAt(1).toUpper();` also produces a compiler error.. 3) `String delims = "\\."; //full stop as delimiter` 4) The code loses the full-stop..

Comment: BTW - an answer can be deleted or edited by the owner.  I would prefer to see 'edit'. After an edit, I get the opportunity to change a down-vote that is otherwise 'locked in'.